# How to evaluate $f(x+ 1) = f(x) + 2x + 1$ at $ x = 2$?

Tags: functions

I'm struggling to evaluate this at $x = 2$ (or, really, any number).

To me, the fact that we have the $f(x)$ on the right hand side of the equation makes this a recursive function, so the calculation will go on indefinitely.

What is wrong with my approach?

Comment: If it is a recursive function, it better have a base case. Your function lacks that. In particular, knowledge of $f(n)$ for any $n \in \mathbb N$ would be sufficient for this problem.

Comment: I see, so, for example, knowing that $f(x) = x^2$ then when $x = 2$ the answer for $f(x + 1) = 1^2  + (2)(1) + 1 = 4$. Am I right?

Answer (score 5):

Write your equation in the form
$$f(x+1)-f(x)=2x+1\ .\tag{1}$$
This is a linear inhomogeneous equation for an unknown function $f$. A particular solution $f_p$ can be guessed, namely $f_p(x)=x^2$. In addition we need the general solution $f_{\rm hom}$ of the associated homogeneous problem $$f(x+1)-f(x)=0\ .\tag{2}$$ Now $(2)$ just says that $f_{\rm hom}$ has to be a periodic function of period $1$. It follows that the general solution of $(1)$ is
$$f(x)=x^2 + g(x)\ ,$$
whereby $g$ is an **arbitrary** function of period $1$.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is $$f(x)=x^2$$ since $$f(x+1)=x^2+2x+1=f(x)+2x+1$$, so $$f(2)=4$$